# Perl Dumping array of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, io

Pretty much just starting out in perl and having some trouble finding out where i am going wrong astray on these 2 subs. They should be reading and writing an array of hashes.. I had the code working when it was just storing a single hash, but since i've tried to adapt it to an array of hashes it seems to have gone quite awry and just writes a single membersDb = [] each time

```
sub ReadData {
    my($input) = new FileHandle "<$dat_file";
    local($/) = "";
    my($str) = <$input>;
    close $input;

    print "Input: $str";

    my($membersDb);
    eval $str;
    my(@current_members) = @$membersDb;
}

sub WriteData {
    my (@data) = @_;
    my $str = Data::Dumper->Dump([ \@data ], [ '$membersDb' ]);
    my($out) = new FileHandle ">$dat_file";
    print $out $str;
    close $out;
}
```

Comment: You should probably use the [`JSON` module](http://metacpan.org/module/JSON)  to serialise data structures like this

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in my comment, there are better options for serialising Perl data than `Data::Dumper`, and [`JSON`](http://metacpan.org/module/JSON) is one of the better ones

However, if you have a reason to use `Data::Dumper` then you should set the `Terse` option so that it doesn't generate variable names like `$VAR1` or, in your case, `$membersDb`. You should also use [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) rather than reading the file and applying `eval` to the contents

This code works as expected

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

use constant MEMBERS_FILE => 'members.dat';

my $members_db = do MEMBERS_FILE;

my @data = @$members_db;

write_data(@data);

sub write_data {
    open my $fh, '>', MEMBERS_FILE or die $!;
    local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
    print $fh Dumper(\@_);
}
```